# Parsing XML creates not well-formed error in python

Tags: python, xml

I am attempting to parse an XML document from the url https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/all/, using the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib.request

url = 'https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/all/'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
tree = ET.fromstring(response)
```

However, I am getting the error `ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0`

What do I need to do in order to convert this to a python object? I am sure this is an XML document, and it appears to parse fine when opened in a browser.

Comment: "line 1, column 0" suggests the problem is right at the beginning. "I am sure this is an XML document"—are you? Does your code definitely get the same `response` that you see in a browser? Have you printed it out and looked at it or inspected it in a debugger?

Comment: Hmmm. There seem to be a lot of \n characters in the response, which shouldn't be there. I guess the better questions are why are these appearing, and is there a way of grabbing the url that will give me parseable code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely getting back json. To verify, try printing the value of `info()` on the HTTPResponse object and look at the "Content-Type":

```py
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(response.info())
```

To request XML, create a Request object and set the header (printing tree for testing):

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib.request

url = "https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/all/"

request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={"Content-Type": "application/xml"})
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
tree = ET.parse(response)
print(ET.tostring(tree.getroot()).decode())
```

this will print (truncated to fit SO):

```xml
<MarketList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Markets><MarketData><ID>2721</ID><Name>Which party will win the 2020 U.S....
```